# ALTER SYSTEM and database restart

Tags: oracle

I was under the impression that when one uses the ALTER SYSTEM statement, the new setting is in effect as long as the instance is up / database is mounted:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_2013.htm#SQLRF00902

After a reboot the setting should revert to its old value.
I have done the below change, shut down and started the instance back up and the new setting is still in effect. Any ideas?

```
SQL> show parameter SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
sec_case_sensitive_logon             boolean     TRUE



SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE;

System altered.


-------Restarted the database---------------------------

SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE;

System altered.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that link you provided, you have to look for the **SCOPE** parameter. By default is Both, if you're using SPFILE (which is the most common), means it will save on the SPFILE and change in memory as well.

Comment: ie, do `ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE SCOPE=MEMORY;`

Answer (score -1):

Hugepage and SGA change require reboot.

1. su - oracle

sqlplus / as sysdba

alter system set memory_max_target=11520m scope=spfile;

--assuming an spfile is used

alter system set memory_target=11520m scope=spfile;

--assuming an spfile is used

2. shutdown the DB
3. start the DB

Comment: This doesn't answer the question